# how to select 3 columns data as single column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Kwd_UploadRecored` in SQL Server:

```
ID  Primary_Kwd                             Sec_Kwd                                         Main_Kwd
1   Man,One Man,architecture,Boy            Arrival,Sigle Man , Business Man ,Male          aspirations,One Person
2   Woman,attire,Girl                       Girl,Girls,Female,Blueprint,Carrying,           Teenage Girl,Only Girls
3   Grand father,Man,caucasian appearance   cheerful, Family,Fatherhood,Family Member,      Male Parent,
4   Baby ,clothes,color image               growth,Babies,Child,Happiness                   Children,Toddlers,differential focus,
```

I want to select data from the `Primary_Kwd` , `Sec_kwd`,`Main_kwd` with distinct like this:

```
Kwds
man
one man
architecture
boy
arrival
Single man
Business man
Male 
.
.
etc
```

I am using the following code but this  is only for one column

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') data
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         #temp.PM_AssetID,Cast ('<M>'
         + replace(Replace(#temp.Primary_kwd, ',', '</M><M>'),'&','&amp;')
         + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM #temp) AS A
CROSS APPLY 
    Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Please help me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write a function to split values based on comma and then try using that on the columns above using union all.

Comment: See the updated question i have already using the split function. but this works for only  one column @Azar

Comment: Can you check the above comment. I asked you to apply this on both the columns and use union all to get the desired resultset i.e Select function (col1) union all Select function(col2)

Comment: Not able to get you @Azar :(

Comment: Wherever you have `Primary_kwd` in your query, change it to `Primary_kwd+','+Sec_kwd+','+Main_kwd`. You may subsequently have to filter out "empty" results.

Comment: @Turophile, wow! That's smart.

Comment: Can you check my answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNION` to remove duplicates:

```
;WITH CtePrimary AS(
    SELECT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Item)) AS Item
    FROM Kwd_UploadRecorded k
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(k.Primary_Kwd, ",") s
),
CteSec AS(
    SELECT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Item)) AS Item
    FROM Kwd_UploadRecorded k
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(k.Sec_Kwd, ",") s
),
CteMain AS(
    SELECT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Item)) AS Item
    FROM Kwd_UploadRecorded k
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(k.Main_Kwd, ",") s
)
SELECT * FROM CtePrimary UNION
SELECT * FROM CteSec UNION
SELECT * FROM CteMain
```

---

As per Turophile's comment, you can rid of the `UNION` by concatenating the `kwd`s first before splitting them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Item)) AS Item
FROM Kwd_UploadRecorded k
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(k.kPrimary_kwd + ',' + k.Sec_kwd + ',' + k.Main_kwd, ",") s
```

Comment: If the characters `&` `<` `>` `"` `'` is used with the words then its working or not ?? @wewesthemenace

Comment: They should work. See, @Turophiles comment. I think that's a better approach.

Comment: If i want to use `order by asc` then where I put this line ??  @wewesthemenace

Comment: In the end, add `ORDER BY Item ASC`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Create a `Spit` function and use `Cross Aplly`

**Main Query**

```
    SELECT Distinct T.ID
        ,S.Data
    FROM Kwd_UploadRecored AS T
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(isnull(T.Primary_Kwd+ ',','')  + isnull(Sec_Kwd+',','') + ',' + isnull(Main_Kwd+',' ,'') ) AS S
    WHERE S.Value > ''
```

**Split Function Code**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @RowData nvarchar(MAX),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data varchar(8000)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
    Select * 
    from #temp
    cross apply fnSplit(Primary_Kwd,',')a
    where a.value > '' 
union all
    Select b.value 
    from #temp
    cross apply fnSplit(Sec_Kwd,',')b
    where b.value > '' 
union all
    Select c.value 
    from #temp
    cross apply fnSplit(Main_Kwd,',')c
    where c.Value > ''
```